# When trying to read a file and print it, it returns an empty list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read the contents of a file that I previously added to, and I want to append it to a list and print that to the console. When I run, it only prints empty lists. The file that I want it to read from only has 6 rows of 7 periods, with no spaces in between.

Here is my code:

```
list = []

def write():
    with open("board.txt", "w") as x:
        for each in range(6):
            x.write("......" + "\n")
        start("board.txt")

def start(x):
    with open(x) as f:
        for line in f:
            b = line.read()
            c = b.strip()
            x = list.append(c)
        print(list)

write()
```

And here is the output:

[]

Here is what the file (board.txt) looks like:

```
.......
.......
.......
.......
.......
.......
```

Please help, I’m new to code and this is really frustrating.

Comment: You opened `board.txt` in write-only mode, so you can't read from it under the same `with` context manager.

Comment: you should start a new list with a shorthand like `x = []` (or more clearly `x = list()`) outside the loop and use _its_ `.append()` method .. you may also want to give it another name (as you use `x` as the path argument)

Answer (score 2):

The `start("board.txt")` has to be a tab or 4 spaces further to the left or the file wasn't closed correctly. And please do not overwrite built-ins. Global variables that change aren't a good idea.

```
def write():
    with open("board.txt", "w") as x:
        for each in range(6):
            x.write("......" + "\n")
    start("board.txt")

def start(x):
    array = []
    with open(x) as f:
        for line in f:
            array.append(line.strip())
        print(array)

write()
```

Comment: x is overwriting the filename

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon I fixed it

Comment: You should also consider explaining why the global `array` variable can be problematic and how calling `start` from `within` write my be an issue as well.

Comment: I know why global variables can be problematic, but I don't know why calling start from within write may be an issue(assuming the file from write is closed correctly)

Comment: Functionally it would work as written.  It's more of a logical thing.  If you're writing a file, would you also expect it to take some other action?  If you notice Gwang-Jin Kim's answer splits it into a `write` and `read` that aren't associated with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is problematic:

```
def start(x):
    with open(x) as f:
        for line in f:
            b = line.read()
            c = b.strip()
            x = list.append(c)
        print(list)
```

`line` is the content of a line in `f` - so the file.
But you use `line` as a handler for a file - while it is a string with the content of a file - in this case ".......".
Second - from where comes `list`? You print it.
I would do what you want like this:

```
def write(filename="board.txt"):
    with open(filename, "w") as fout:
        for each in range(6):
            fout.write("......" + "\n")


def read(filename="board.txt"):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        return [line.strip() for line in fin] # or: fin.readlines()

write()
read()
```

Comment: he overwrote the list builtin at the start of the script with `list = []`

Comment: his original script strips each line, make sure your list comprehension also applies `.strip()`

Comment: While I personally like using a list comprehension, as the OP does not use them adding them here without explaining the change does not provide a good learning experience.

Comment: thanks - yes, true!

Comment: Although this was helpful in getting an actual output. When I run this it still prints the \n though, and to get rid of that I have to strip, but I don’t know how with this kind of code (I haven’t learned this yet). Can anyone help? Thank you though.

Comment: @ZamzamaAhmadi I added .strip() to line. Now it should work.